# Can I protect a Firebase project from within the console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, firebase-console

When I go to my Firebase console I can simply walk straight into any project and browse the content. I just want to know if there's ay way to add an extra layer of security such that if *should* someone get into my Firebase console they cannot access the sensitive project information.

Comment: If someone can get to your console, that means you're already logged into your Google account, which means the individual can then access almost everything else under that account.  This is probably a bigger problem than your Firebase console.  Protect your account password.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't think its a programming related question, I'll try to answer the key points.

Once someone is in your Firebase Console there's no way out. Not only the person has access to Firebase but your everything Google.

Now the maximum someone can do as I think of is delete your project from Firebase Console. In that case, you might want to [restore](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en) your project from Google [Cloud Platform Console Projects & Folders](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) Page. Again this I believe isn't a programming related question so I might have missed some points maybe but overall better to simply click that 'Sign Out' Button after you've worked. It's more of a client-side measure.